# setting the value of a new column according to the value of an existing column using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

here's the existing table:

```
var Main = sequelize.define('Main', {
   id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(100),
    allowNull: true
    }
});
```

then I add a new column:

```
var Main = sequelize.define('Main', {
   id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(100),
    allowNull: true
    },
   status: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(100),
    allowNull: true
    }
});
```

and I want to set the value of status equal to the value of id +1, i tried the setter and getter definitions as below, but it's not working:

```
var Main = sequelize.define('Main', {
   id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(100),
    allowNull: true
    },

   status: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(100),
    allowNull: true,
    get: function () {
             var num = getDataValue('id');
             return num;
        }, 
    set: function (val) {
             this.setDataValue('status',val+1);
        }
    }
});
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The setter is expecting that you send that column when you create the record.
You could:

1. Send an empty value for status and change your setter to:

```js
set: function () {
  this.setDataValue('status', this.getDataValue('id') + 1);
}
```

2. Change your setter to the id property

```js
set: function (value) {
  this.setDataValue('status', value + 1);
}
```

Comment: but the status didn't change,how can i make the setter and getter work?